# While creating react app i am getting an EPERM: operation not permitted, mkdir 'my-app' error

Tags: reactjs

[image]

I am trying to create react app but when I m using `npx create-react-app myapp` its showing an Eperm error and when I am using `npm install -g create-react-app` its showing npm fund . I tried to solve it by reinstalling node js but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Install `create-react-app` globally first, like:

```
npm install -g create-react-app
```

And then, you can create your app, like:

```
npx create-react-app myapp
```

Comment: i have tried many times to solve it this way but its throwing the same error

Comment: It's a permission denied issue. The system is not letting him do the `mkdir` operation. He is inside  **C:/myapp** and you can not create or edit files in C drive without admin permissions.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you are creating myapp in **C drive**, you may not have write permissions for that. In order to do this either use another drive(run `cd "drive:/folder_name"`)or run your command  in command prompt with administrator permissions.
Right click on command prompt and select run as administrator. You can also change drive by simply opening that folder in vscode and then the vscode terminal will automatically switch to that folder.